# Use passed parameters in for loop - React Native

Tags: loops, react-native, for-loop, navigation

I have two classes. In the first one I am fetching from an API. Then I am passing the data to the other class using props.navigation. I can display the data but I want to use those data in a For loop as in this code:

```
 renderText = () => {
    const obje = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
    Console.log(obje)  //this prints correctly
for (let i = 0; i < obje.length; i++) {
    console.log(obje)  //this doesnt print anything 
    if (obje[i].name != null) {
    console.log(obje}
    }
}
```

EDIT:
When I try to print `const obje`, it prints. But when I try to print `obje` inside the for loop it doesnt, so I guess its not even going through the for loop at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190058/discussion-on-question-by-doedoe-use-passed-parameters-in-for-loop-react-nativ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
renderText = () => {
        const obje = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
        console.log(obje)  //this prints correctly

          Object.keys(obje).map((item) => {
            if(item == 'name'){
             console.log(obje[item])//YOU CAN PRINT NAME'S VALUE LIKE THIS
             }
          })

    }
```

Comment: Its an object, it throws an error: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'obje.map')

Comment: @DoeDoe Can you please share your api response that got into previous screen?

Comment: It has this strcture:  { name: "something", id: 12323, keyValues: [{...}, ... }

Comment: Why you added keyValue in const obje? I am not trying to print that, thats just part of the structure.

Comment: Error:  undefined is not a function (evaluating 'obje.map')

Comment: @DoeDoe its obje not obj

Comment: how can I print just the name? that prints everything

Comment: Are you getting solution?

Comment: I didnt try, I think I am going with another approach because I see that I dont have to iterate. I just call .name directly. Thanks! Upvoted